# Как проверить файл на ошибки форматирования?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать программу, которая открывает текстовый файл, считывает данные и выводит информацию в браузере.

1. Создать текстовый файл.
   Исходный текстовый файл имеет следующий формат:

   `21.01.01 / 12:00 / подготовка к сессии`
   `22.01.01 / 14:00 / сдача сессии`
   `23.01.01 / 15:00 / гуляй`
   `...`
2. Открыть файл, считать данные.
   Данные должны отображаться в браузере в виде таблицы.
3. При написании программы нужно учесть следующие исключения:

   - текстового файла может не быть;
   - Могут быть ошибки при составлении текстового файла.

==================================================================
Так вот все сделано кроме последнего пункта.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test (PHP)</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$fname = '1.txt';
$delim = '/';
if (file_exists($fname) && is_readable($fname)) {
    $file = file($fname);
    echo "<table border = '1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Дата:</th>
    <th>Время:</th>
    <th>Событие:</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach ($file as $item) {
        $newItem = explode($delim, $item);
        echo "<tr>
        <td>$newItem[0]</td>
        <td>$newItem[1]</td>
        <td>$newItem[2]</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo "File not found!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Как проверять ошибки формата файла.
То есть, **если в файле лишний "/" или его совсем нет, программа должна показывать ошибку!**

Comment: Как я понял, нужно просто регулярным выражениям проверить каждою строку $item
Помогите реализовать, плс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постарался отделить логику от представления.

```
<?php

function parseRow($s, $delim = '/')
{
    $s = trim($s);
    $regex = '/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s*' . preg_quote($delim) . '\s*(\d+:\d+)\s*' . preg_quote($delim) . '\s*(.*)$/';

    if (!preg_match($regex, $s, $m)) {
        return false;
    }

    return array($m[1], $m[2], $m[3]);
}

function loadRows($filename)
{
    if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($fname)) {
        return null;
    }

    $result = array();
    $f = fopen($filename, 'r');
    while (!feof($f)) {
        $s = fgets($f);
        if (!$s) {
            continue;
        }

        $result[] = parseRow($s);
    }
    fclose($f);

    return $result;
}

$rows = loadRows('1.txt');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test (PHP)</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php if (!$rows): ?>
    File not found!
<?php else: ?>
    <table border = "1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Дата:</th>
        <th>Время:</th>
        <th>Событие:</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <?php if (!$row): ?>
                    <td><?=htmlspecialchars($row[0])?></td>
                    <td><?=htmlspecialchars($row[1])?></td>
                    <td><?=htmlspecialchars($row[2])?></td>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <td colspan="3">Row error</td>
                <?php endif ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```